# Name of Embedded Node

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a Java Application that I am connecting to an Elasticsearch cluster as a client(read only) Node using embedded Elasticsearch. I am not setting the node.name property in the elastiscsearch.yml file. Is it possible to get the name that Elasticsearch has assigned randomly to this node? I would prefer to get this information via the Java API so my application can display the node name on a status screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get it like this if you have an instantiated `org.elasticsearch.node.Node`

`node.settings().get("name");`

You can also get it from the nodeStats call on the cluster admin. This will mirror the results you would get from the node/stats REST api, something like this:

`ActionFuture<NodesStatsResponse> nsr =  client().admin().cluster().nodesStats(new NodesStatsRequest());

  System.out.println(nsr.get().toString());`

```

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "unitTest",
  "nodes" : {
    "1" : {
      "timestamp" : 1384212017873,
      "name" : "Naga",
      "transport_address" : "local[1]",
      "hostname" : "marks-Latitude-E6510",
      "attributes" : {
        "http.enabled" : "false",
        "local" : "true"
      },
      "indices" : {
         .... blah blah blah
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```